# Bootstrapping for sequential conversion data

Tags: bootstrap

I have event data of the form

```
State1 → State2 → State3
```

involving people moving through the above sequence. At each stage the person will either move onto the next (e.g. going from State1 → State2) or they will leave the process.

For a group of N users at State1, I have measurements of their onward behaviour in a tabular dataset of the form:

```
person_id | state1 (y/n) | state2 (y/n) | state3 (y/n)
1 | y | y | n # this person dropped out after state 2
2 | y | n | n # this person dropped out after state 1
3 | y | y | y # this person didn't drop out
```

and am naively estimating the transition rates (State1 → State2; and State2 → State3) by doing e.g.

$$
R_{1,2} = N(\text{State}_2) / N(\text{State}_1)
$$
i.e. the number of people at State2 divided by the number of people who were in State1. Every person who was in State1 either goes to State2 or drops out of the process. Likewise, every person who ends up in State2 either goes into State3 or drops out of the process.

I want to estimate the distribution of the $R_{1,2}$. I have been using bootstrapping methods and then calculating $R_{1,2}$ on the bootstrapped data in order to build up a distribution.

My question is: how should I estimate the distribution of $R_{2,3}$? I think I have two choices

1. from my original dataset, resample the people in State2, check how many go to State3 and then calculate the ratio.
2. from my original dataset, resample the people in State1 and keep only those who go to State2. Resample the people in State2, check how many go to State3 and then calculate the ratio.

Which of these approaches should I use? Or is there another method that would be more appropriate?